# How records can be retrieved based on three conditions?

Tags: sql, hql

I'm new to HQL. I need to fetch all the records from table A based on the following 2 condition using HQL/SQL query:
Person ID  which satisfies both these conditions "(Music < 100) and (Dance != Normal)" (in Table B) and whose Place and Country is A and AAA (in Table C).

Tables below:

[[image: TABLE B]

[[image: TABLE C]

[[image: TABLE A]

How can I fetch these records based on this three conditions. Could someone help me.

The output should be

Record having ID as 100 in Table A since it has place and value as 'A' and 'AA'. And it also has both Music and Dance skills with Music value greater than 100 and Dance value is not like 'Normal'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
*
from a 
inner join b as music on a.id = music.person_id and music.skills = 'Music'
inner join b as dance on a.id = dance.person_id and dance.skills = 'Dance'
inner join c on a.id = c.id 
where c.place = 'A' and c.country = 'AAA'
and music.score < '100'
and dance.score <> 'Normal'
```

You will have a problem attempting to use less than on the column "score" which is text and not numeric, see test cases below

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable(
>    Value VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
> );
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('100');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('a');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('aa');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('bbb');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('cccc');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('99');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('9');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('1');
> INSERT INTO mytable(Value) VALUES ('19');
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from mytable where value < '100'
> ```

> ```
> | value |
> | :---- |
> | 1     |
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from mytable where value > '100'
> ```

> ```
> | value |
> | :---- |
> | a     |
> | aa    |
> | bbb   |
> | cccc  |
> | 99    |
> | 9     |
> | 19    |
> ```

> ```
> select
> *
> from mytable where cast(value as integer) > 100
> ```

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "a"
> ```

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a9f97a42cbb550e2158ff67cb8d03672)*

Comment: But it doesnt return anything. There is no way to use comparision operator on strings? In my case it should return ID 100 record from Table A since it has place and value as A and AA. And it also Music and Dance skills with Music value greater than 100 and Dance value is not like 'Normal'

Comment: I tried using as follows with cast function but it doesnt return anything.. music.score < CAST('100' as UNSIGNED) and dance.score not like 'Normal'

Comment: try it with one condition at a time, get that to work, then move on to the next. You can use `<` on strings but it does not work like it does on numbers see the extra information in the answer. Note you need to cast the column to a number, not the compare to figure `CAST(music.score as UNSIGNED) < 100` but be aware of the possible conversion errors that will result